# Blowfish example where automatically pad and unpad the key to size

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, blowfish

Blowfish is capable of strong encryption and can use key sizes up to 56 bytes (a 448 bit key).
 The key must be a multiple of 8 bytes (up to a maximum of 56).

I want to write example will automatically pad and unpad the key to size. Because Blowfish creates blocks of 8 byte encrypted output, the output is also padded and unpadded to multiples of 8 bytes.

actually want to write java code to simulate-
http://webnet77.com/cgi-bin/helpers/blowfish.pl

I am using info for tool-

```
ALGORITM = "Blowfish";
HEX KEY = "92514c2df6e22f079acabedce08f8ac3";
PLAIN_TEXT = "sangasong@song.com"
```

Tool returns-

```
CD3A08381467823D4013960E75E465F0B00C5E3BAEFBECBB
```

Please suggest.

Tried the java code:

```
public class TestBlowfish
{
    final String KEY = "92514c2df6e22f079acabedce08f8ac3";
    final String PLAIN_TEXT = "sangasong@song.com";
    byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(KEY); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    try 
    {
        byte[] encrypted = encrypt(keyBytes, PLAIN_TEXT);
        System.out.println( "Encrypted hex: " + Hex.encodeHexString(encrypted));

    }catch (GeneralSecurityException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, String plainText) throws GeneralSecurityException
{
    SecretKey secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key, "Blowfish");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret_key);

    return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
}
```

Result -

```
Encrypted hex: 525bd4bd786a545fe7786b0076b3bbc2127425f0ea58c29d
```

Comment: Suggest... what ? Have you tried anything so far ?
Why do you need to pad a key ? It should be generated at the correct size. Why do you need to unpad it then ?

Comment: @Coconop, i have edited my question. please see what i have tried so far.

Comment: Good ! Now did you run it and encounter any error ?

Comment: no error. but output is not same as tool. our client encrypt using webnet77 tool and sending us the encrypted code.adding output in original post.

Comment: @Coconop ,Actually tried various ways and sequence to encrypt but never got same result as the tool.

Comment: You have nicely improved your question :)
So your key is a multiple of 8 so it should not be padded. However you plain text is probably padded: maybe the script has a different method for padding ?
Why do you want exactly the same output ? It should not be a problem if your soft is able to decrytpt correctly what it has encrypted...

Comment: thanks for your feedback for improvement;-)  if i am getting the encrypted code which is same as output from tool, how can i decrypt the code at my end to get same text. need to get same encryption first, right? thats what i am trying to do. can you please suggest and help with some code.thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the script uses an incorrect version of PKCS#7 padding that does not pad when the size of the input is already dividable by the block size - both for the key and the plaintext. Furthermore it uses ECB mode encryption. Neither of which should be used in real life scenarios.

The following code requires the Bouncy Castle provider to be added to the JCE (`Service.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())`) and that the Hex class of Bouncy Castle libraries is in the class path.

Warning: only tested with limited input, does not cut the key size if the size of the key is larger than the maximum.

[image]

WARNING: THE FOLLOWING CODE IS NOT CRYPTOGRAPHICALLY SOUND

```
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class BadBlowfish {
        private static SecretKey createKey(String theKey) {
        final byte[] keyData = theKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        final byte[] paddedKeyData = halfPadPKCS7(keyData, 8);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(paddedKeyData, "Blowfish");
        return secret;
    }

    private static byte[] halfUnpadPKCS7(final byte[] paddedPlaintext, int blocksize) {
        int b = paddedPlaintext[paddedPlaintext.length - 1] & 0xFF;
        if (b > 0x07) {
            return paddedPlaintext.clone();
        }
        return Arrays.copyOf(paddedPlaintext, paddedPlaintext.length - b);
    }

    private static byte[] halfPadPKCS7(final byte[] plaintext, int blocksize) {
        if (plaintext.length % blocksize == 0) {
            return plaintext.clone();
        }

        int newLength = (plaintext.length / blocksize + 1) * blocksize;
        int paddingLength = newLength - plaintext.length;

        final byte[] paddedPlaintext = Arrays.copyOf(plaintext, newLength);
        for (int offset = plaintext.length; offset < newLength; offset++) {
            paddedPlaintext[offset] = (byte) paddingLength;
        }
        return paddedPlaintext;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding");
        SecretKey key = createKey("123456781234567");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] plaintextData = cipher.doFinal(Hex.decode("085585C60B3D23257763E6D8BB0A0891"));
        byte[] unpaddedPlaintextData = halfUnpadPKCS7(plaintextData, cipher.getBlockSize());

        String plaintextHex = Hex.toHexString(unpaddedPlaintextData);
        System.out.println(plaintextHex);
        String plaintext = new String(unpaddedPlaintextData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(plaintext);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @owlstead. I got the exact solution what i was looking for with minor edits to your code. great help!!

Comment: do you think it will not work when i send the encrypted code from URL?? As stand alone java program works great...but I am getting Exception - Getting javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher?

Comment: Always URL encode the ciphertext. Make sure that the ciphertext is identical when you send and receive it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the relevance of this question: IMHO there is no point of getting the same output as this script: you have no guaranty about how secure/efficient it is...
What raises my eyebrow is the part about the padding: there are several solution to pad a block, some of then are simple but very unsecured, and *maybe* this script is using one of these "bad" solution.

Did you check that your program is able to retrieve the correct plain text ? (you will need to code the matching `decrypt` function).
If so, it means that it works correctly and it can be used for whatever your original purpose was, regardless what the ouput of this script is...